# Why my Database doesn't seem to be install?

Tags: android

My app using a database.
On my nexus 4, not rooted, 4.2.1, the app is working and the database is correclty installed.
But on my Iconia A501 4.0.3, rooted, the app isn't working and a message said the database doesn't exist.

The database is in a script file in the asset directory, here's the code used into DB.java:

```
    package fr.app.tutorielfragment;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;


public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 28;

    // Database Name
//    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BASE2.db";



    public static final String METIER_TABLE_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME + ";";
    Context context;


    public DB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // Store the context for later use
        this.context = context;
        Toast.makeText(context, "DB context",1000).show();



    }


    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String a = null;
        Log.d("aaa","Création des bases");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Création des bases",1000).show();
                        // creer la base avec le script
    executeSQLScript(database, "install7.sql");                     
        Log.d("aaa","Création des bases");
        a=a;
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Lorsque l'on change le numéro de version de la base on supprime la
        // table puis on la recrée
        if (oldVersion < DATABASE_VERSION) {    
            try
            {
                context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
                onCreate(db);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Supression des bases",1000).show();
                //              db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + "base_codematiere" + ";");

            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "ERREUR pdt Supression des bases",1000).show();
                // TODO Handle Script Failed to Execute
                e=e;
                e=e;
            }

            db.close();
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "onUpgrade",1000).show();
    }    

    public void removeAll()
    {
        // db.delete(String tableName, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs);
        // If whereClause is null, it will delete all rows.
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // helper is object extends SQLiteOpenHelper
        db.delete(DATABASE_NAME, null, null);
//      db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TAB_USERS_GROUP, null, null);
    }

    private void executeSQLScript(SQLiteDatabase database, String dbname) 
    {
        int num=0;
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try
        {
            inputStream = assetManager.open(dbname);
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) 
            {
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            String[] createScript = outputStream.toString().split(";");
            for (int i = 0; i < createScript.length; i++) 
            {
                String sqlStatement = createScript[i].trim();
                // TODO You may want to parse out comments here
                if (sqlStatement.length() > 0) 
                {
                    database.execSQL(sqlStatement + ";");
                    num=num+1;
                }
            }
            len=createScript.length;

        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Handle Script Failed to Load
            e=e;
            e=e;
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            // TODO Handle Script Failed to Execute
            e=e;
            e=e;
        }
    }



    }
```

can someone can explain me why it's working fine on my nexus4 and why isn't working on the A501? and how to do to lunch my app on the A501?

Thx in advance,

UPdate: LogCat:

```
04-02 19:18:53.847: D/dalvikvm(15243): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2160K, 29% free 10164K/14151K, paused 21ms
04-02 19:18:53.877: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(15243): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = statement aborts at 2: [BEGIN TRANSACTION;] cannot start a transaction within a transaction, db=/data/data/fr.app.tutorielfragment/databases/BASE2.db
04-02 19:18:53.877: D/aaa(15243): Création des bases
04-02 19:18:53.977: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(15243): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: ID_DANGER_CLASSE_1, db=/data/data/fr.app.tutorielfragment/databases/BASE2.db
04-02 19:18:53.977: D/AndroidRuntime(15243): Shutting down VM
04-02 19:18:53.977: W/dalvikvm(15243): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a681f8)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ID_DANGER_CLASSE_1: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM ID_DANGER_CLASSE_1 ;
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1538)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at fr.app.tutorielfragment.A_Page_Classe1.RD_Database_InfoClasse(A_Page_Classe1.java:47)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at fr.app.tutorielfragment.A_Page_Classe1.onActivityCreated(A_Page_Classe1.java:32)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1468)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1012)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:881)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1366)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12728)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12728)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12728)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2118)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12728)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-02 19:18:53.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15243):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try a re-install of your app. May be the migration is not happening properly.

Comment: I've re-install and attempt to understand in debug, but not working any more

Comment: What does your log say? Can you post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
no such table: ID_DANGER_CLASSE_1: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM ID_DANGER_CLASSE_1 ;
```

From the logs, looks like your tables haven't been created yet.

```
3.877: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(15243): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = statement aborts at 2: [BEGIN TRANSACTION;] cannot start a transaction within a transaction, db=/data/data/fr.app.tutorielfragment/databases/BASE2.db
04-02 19:18:53.877: D/aaa(15243): Création des bases
```

Try to debug executeSQLScript method, and see where it is failing.

After this line

```
database.execSQL(sqlStatement + ";");
```

Try printing out the value of sqlStatement.

Comment: i've this error in debug: 04-02 20:31:40.827: D/DBHelper(18442): SQLite exception: cannot start a transaction within a transaction, so in my script i've remove BEGIN TRANSACTION at the first line of the database script and seem there's no pb now...